# Fixed Div overlaps scrollbar of static div

Tags: css, layout, position, css-position, fixed

I'm having trouble to to style my layout like I want it to. I have a content area `#content` (the grey you can see in the example image) with a yellow element inside. This div is `position:static;height:100%;`. Now I have a `#left-panel` div also, with `position:fixed;height:100%;`. The problem is, if the content area has not enough space a horizontally scrollbar appears. This will be overlaped of the fixed div. For me it is all logically, but I don't know how to get around this. My scrollbar of the `#content`-element should be visible the whole width of the window. So it would not be a solution for me to just reduce the width of the content if the panel is in view.

The whole css:

```
#content{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:grey;
}
#left-panel{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Can somebody help me fixing this with pure CSS?

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a2wn8x5z/1/

Comment: can you provide some fiddle link

Comment: see the updated answer, perhaps that's what you want

Comment: Sorry, no that is not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your wrapper element is `position:fixed;` I think that you are talking about a overlay with a navigation panel on the left. Well, I had a similar situation and found out, that you can't use `position:fixed;` if your parent element is also `position:fixed;`. This will overlap the scrollbar of the parent wrapper (the overlay).

So you have to use `position:absolute;` instead or use this open source plugin to remove the width/height of the scrollbar from your element:

**[Scrollbar Fixer](https://github.com/julmot/jm.ScrollbarLayoutFixer)**

Answer (score 1):

<strike>perhaps your problem is in this code here</strike>

```
<div style="width:110%;border-right:10px solid black;height:200px;background:yellow;"></div>
```

remove the `width:110%;` and it should be good to go.

Here's the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2wn8x5z/2/)

### Edit

I think I misunderstand what's the problem before.

Because on your case, you use `position: fixed;` for `#wrapper` and `#left-panel`, and both use stlye `left: 0`, their position will overlap each other in left from the viewport, you basically need to position the `left` of `#wrapper` not to be in the same position as `#left-panel`, so you need to add this to `#wrapper`

```
left:200px; /* the width of #left-panel (if left panel has border, add it to this too )*/
right:0;
```

and remove

```
width:100%;
```

here's the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2wn8x5z/3/)

to make sure it's what you want, try change the style of the `div` inside `#content` to `width:200%;` and add `margin:20px;`

### Edit Two

the cause for the `scrollbar` to overlap each other is because in the fiddle you use `position: fixed` for the `#wrapper`, thus will not create a `scrollbar` in the `body`, then you add `overflow:auto` in the `#wrapper`, causing the `scrollbar` to be created for the `#wrapper` and not the `body`, so you need to change the `CSS` for `#wrapper` to this

```
#wrapper{
    background:gray;
}
```

I don't include the height because for the `div`, the `height` is based on the child inside it, so you couldn't see the gray background, except you add some `padding` to it.

here's the [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2wn8x5z/7/)

Comment: Sorry, but you misunderstood the question again :P This is what I have wrote "So it would not be a solution for me to just reduce the width of the content if the panel is in view". But this is exactly what you did! The scrollbar is not on the whole window, instead it is only inside the content area. This looks like I am working with framesets and I do not like this look

Comment: sorry, my bad for misunderstanding it for the 2nd time. So what you want is for the `#content` to 100% width of viewport, and when there's a horizontal scroll bar, the scroll bar isn't overlapped by the `#left-panel`, and it need to be only `CSS`?

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what I am searching for

Comment: I know I could find out the width of the scrollbar with JS and then set the width of the left-panel minus the scrollbar width, but I do not like to fix my layout with JavaScript

Comment: @user3631654, updated the answer. I think that's the best that can be done if you insist only to use `CSS`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have to add "position: static;" style into your div, because it's static by default. There are two ways to solve your problem:

Add "position: relative;" into #content selector and declare #content after #left-panel in your HTML.

```
<div id="left-panel"></div>
<div id="content"></div>

#content{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:grey;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yoHxl

Or add "position: relative; z-index: 1" (z-index of #content should be higher of #left-panel's) into #content selector.

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="left-panel"></div>

#content{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:grey;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HgwDx

Best,
Marek

Comment: Sorry but that is not the solution I am searching for. The left-panel should remain in the foreground. Please look at my example image. That is exactly what I try to realize but the left-panel should not overlap the scrollbar of the content!